# Is it possible to save data to two databases using woocommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a word press site using woo commerce cart and i would like to save my Customer details to another sql Server database we have.
Is it possible to do this on a successful payment by saving to two separate databases.
(MySQL and a SQL Server both hosted on Azure)

I know I could alternatively use the CSV export plugin for woo commerce but its a bit to manual for us.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hook `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` and do your SQL connection/update there.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'update_order_so_16833426', 10, 2 );

function update_order_so_16833426( $order_id, $posted )
{
    // do your thing
}
```

I haven't tested, but the code documentation says `$posted` contains an *Array of posted form data*. In case of need, you can get it as well using `$order_data = new WC_Order( $order_id );`

Update, maybe you need to encapsulate the hook into another one to get the timing right:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'do_woocommerce_hook_so_16833426' );

function do_woocommerce_hook_so_16833426()
{
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'update_order_so_16833426', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you brasofilo, I am new to wordpress and php but i'm reading up on all this now. using a hook looks like the way to go. It may be obvious but where do i put the add_action and my new function? Would it be in the form-checkout.php file?

Comment: ahh i think i have it now in woocommerce-functions.php

Comment: @user2329438, no, you should do your own plugin, it's easy and best practice: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web

Comment: Thank you i have done that now but I cant seem to get the hook to fire using woocommerce_checkout_order_processed.  Would it be because of the payment gateway redirect?  wp_head works fine.

Comment: @user2329438, I've updated the code. What do you mean by "`wp_head` works fine"?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ajax request to a custom php page when the user clicks on the final button.

It should be pretty straightforward if you include jquery to grab each input elements value within the footer.php then use ajax to pass those values to a custom php page which can connect to your other database and insert the values.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Jon, im trying to understand the flow of what you are sayin. So on my checkout page that contains all the customer input details there is the woocomerece Place order button that will call my merchant service to take credit card details. I presume this is where i will capture the details? without affecting the redirect to the merchant service how would i go about saving their details to my Sql DB? thanks

Comment: That's correct.

if you add something like this:

`code
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#place_order').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url:'http://YOUR_DOMAIN/YOUR_PHP_PAGE_HERE.php',
     data: $('#billing_first_name').val();
   });
 });
});
`

That should give you the idea. :)